# Space enclosed between a list of numbers and the X-axis

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, calculus-and-analysis

I have lists of numbers, consisting of 8 different numbers in each list.

I will get a line if I display the list as ListLinePlot, the first number will be 1 on the X axis, and the last 8.

Is there a function that will give me this area?

For example, for the list 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7 the area is 25.5.

for the list 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 the area is 31.5

```
a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}
ListLinePlot[a]
```

[image]

Comment: Check the resource function [DiscreteIntegralPlot](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/DiscreteIntegralPlot/) that has many options.

Answer (score 4):

```
a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}
plot = ListLinePlot[a, Filling -> Axis]
plot // DiscretizeGraphics // Area
```

[image]

> `31.5`

```
Integrate[Interpolation[a]@t, {t, Min@a, Max@a}]
```

> `63/2`

Answer (score 3):

Please consult [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1710183/fastest-way-to-find-the-area-under-a-curve-which-is-represented-by-a-list-of-poi) MSE page for reference.

The visualizations clearly show the trapezoids whose area is being calculated. With a list of 2D points called `pts`, define the functions below:

```
tArea[pts_List] := Module[{x, y, xdiff, ydiff},
  x = pts[[All, 1]];
  y = pts[[All, 2]];
  xdiff = Flatten@(Differences /@ Partition[x, 2, 1]);
  ydiff = Flatten@(Mean /@ Partition[y, 2, 1]);
  Plus@(xdiff . ydiff)
  ]

tPlot[pts_List] := ListLinePlot[
  pts
  (*,InterpolationOrder\[Rule]1*)
  , Filling -> Axis
  , FillingStyle -> {Directive[Opacity[0.2], Cyan]}
  , Epilog -> {
    Line[{#, {1, 0} #}] & /@ pts
    , Red, AbsolutePointSize[4], Point@pts
    }
  ]
```

**Examples**

```
pts = Transpose[{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}, Range[8]}]
tArea[pts]
```

> 63/2

```
tPlot[pts]
```

[image]

---

```
x = {1, 2, 3.4, 4.4, 7, 9, 12, 15};
y = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7};
pts = Transpose[{x, y}];
tArea[pts]
```

> 71.7

```
tPlot[pts]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Does this do what you want?

```
fun[list_] := 
  Integrate[
   ListInterpolation[list, {1, 8}, InterpolationOrder -> 1][x], 
   x
  ][[0]][8]

fun[Range[8]]
(* 63/2 *)

fun[Range[0, 7]]
(* 49/2 *)

list = {93.08, 142, 84.2, 95.94, 84.04, 64.9, 104.84, 62.62}
fun[list]
(* 653.77 *)
```

Comment: Yes, this is a great solution

Answer (score 0):

The area is obviously the mean of the first and last point multiplied by the length minus 1:

```
area[list_] := (list[[-1]] + list[[1]])/2 (Length[list] - 1);
```

With this e.g.:

```
area[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}]

(* 63/2*)
```

Comment: the list that I give is just for example.  have many different lists such {93.08, 142, 84.2, 95.94, 84.04, 64.9, 104.84, 62.62} and in that case it won't work.

Comment: If you have a list of lists, you would write: area /@ listoflists

Comment: @DanielHuber Your answer assumes that the numbers will always be strictly increasing and consecutive. That’s pretty restrictive.